# Why can't I use "x = $("p").offset; Top = x().top" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, offset

I am using jQuery and need to get the location of one element.

I wrote the code like this first:

```
 x=$("p").offset;
 Top = x().top; // bug here
```

I find the browser cannot find the top because x() is null here.

So I rewrote it like this:

```
x=$("p").offset;
y=$("p").offset();
Top = y.top;
```

Ok, now it works.

But why??? 
I thought y.top should be same as x().top since x() is $("p").offset().

Comment: `offset` is a **method** not a **property**, that is why it works

Comment: And it returns an object that has properties `left` and `top`. reading the documentation would have answered this yourself

Comment: What you lose by removing the `offset` method from its jQuery object is the `this` context. I suspect there would be pertinent information in the error message reported

Comment: I am curious why `x=$("p").offset` is not working as a function reference. I know it doesn't I am just curious *why*

Comment: And jQuery objects are not functions. `x()` should be throwing error that x is not a function

Comment: Agree to @GetOffMyLawn, offset is a method, but you get it as a property, and maybe there is not a property call offset. So you are getting null there

Comment: An equivalent call would be `p = $('p'); x = p.offset; x.call(p).top`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example

```js
function P() {
  this.pos = {top: 1, left: 1}
}
P.prototype.offset = function() {
  return this.pos
}

const p = new P()
console.info('p.offset().top:', p.offset().top)

const fn = function() {
  return this.pos // won't work when called normally, ie fn()
}

console.info('fn.call(p).top:', fn.call(p).top) // works

const x = p.offset // x is equivalent to fn
console.info('x.call(p).top:', x.call(p).top)
console.info('x().top:', x().top) // doesn't work
```

The last one errors out because the method `offset` (now assigned to `x`) has no `this` context for `return this.pos` to work.

That is why `this` is undefined in that call.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call